# how to programatically add chart control to ASP.net c# page

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am creating a report application which queries a database and calculates the sales figures for staff. The result from the query is stored in a dataset. At the moment, I am dragging the chart control from the toolbox onto the page to create a control. This chart control sits in a div tag called slideshow as I'm using jQuery to create a slideshow. Each chart is bound to a row from the dataset.

However, the issue I am having now is that if a new staff is added, I will have to keep messing around with the web page to display a chart for the new staff. Is there a way in which I can say, "For each row in the dataset, create a chart control in the slideshow div tag ?"

Answer (score 0):

Interactions between ASP.net and jquery can be a little tricky because you are dealing with server side vs. client side.  What I suggest you do is create a list from the server side (e.g. produce a static JSON list in javascript or use AJAX), then use jquery to create your charts for each staff in your JSON list.

Answer (score 0):

agree with about idea of getting server to return JSON and doing all in jquery - you should have a look at the new-ish jquery templates very easy to turn your json into a set of div tags formatted as your require.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do what you ask.

Suppose that you have a Dataset ds with some rows.  You want to create a chart for each row.  Here's what you can do:

1) Declare an ASP Panel on your page:

```
<asp:Panel runat='server' id='pnlCharts' />
```

2) In your code-behind, you'll want to write something like this:

```
Dataset ds = getMyData();
foreach(Datarow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
Chart chart = new Chart();
// Add code to design a chart from a *single* row
Panel.Controls.Add(chart);
}
```

**Update:**
I though about your question some more.  You might also consider using the ASP Repeater to do what you want.  You can also write the charts directly to the page where you want using Chart.RenderControl().